# How do extract just the date (without the time) from an integer field in SQLite3?

Tags: date, time, sqlite

I have a small SQLite3 DB that has an integer field called "dt". It stores date and time.

I am having trouble extracting just the date from the field. However, doing a "select date(dt) from log2" returns nothing. I've tried strftime() as well, but no cigar.

Please help. This is driving me insane.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if the Date in dt is wellformed then the result shoeld be the date from a datetime column

```
select date('2011-01-01 23:55:55');
```

should receive

```
2011-01-01
```

but
    select date('2011-01-01 23:55:5');

would receive nothing

so the dt coloum have to be wellformed